# How to set data in fillInIntent

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a list view in my home screen widget and I want to launch a pending intent when the item is clicked. I referred to [this](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/appwidgets/collections#behavior) and set a fillInIntent for every list item and then set a pending intent template which triggers the broadcast receiver of the widget:

```
class WidgetProvider : HomeWidgetProvider() {
    override fun onUpdate(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetIds: IntArray, widgetData: SharedPreferences) {

        appWidgetIds.forEach { widgetId ->
            val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_layout).apply {

                val todosStr  = widgetData.getString("todos", "null")
                val todos = ArrayList<HashMap<String, Any>>()
                val todosRemoteView = RemoteViews.RemoteCollectionItems.Builder()
                if(todosStr != "null"){
                    val jObj = JSONObject(todosStr)
                    val jsonArry = jObj.getJSONArray("todos")
                    for (i in 0 until jsonArry.length()) {
                        val todo = HashMap<String, Any>()
                        val obj = jsonArry.getJSONObject(i)
                        todo["id"] = obj.getInt("id")
                        todos.add(todo)

                        val view = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.each_todo).apply {
                            setTextViewText(R.id.each_todo_container_text, todo["taskName"].toString())

                            val fillInIntent = Intent().apply {
                                Bundle().also { extras ->
                                    extras.putInt("todo_id", todo["id"].toString().toInt())//this isn't working for some reason
                                    putExtras(extras)
                                }
                            }
                            Log.d("debugging",  "id received is ${todo["id"].toString()}" )
                            setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.each_todo_container_text, fillInIntent)
                        }

                        todosRemoteView.addItem(todo["id"].toString().toInt().toLong(), view)
                    }
                }

                setRemoteAdapter(
                        R.id.todos_list,
                        todosRemoteView
                    .build()
                )

                val pendingIntentx: PendingIntent = Intent(
                        context,
                        WidgetProvider::class.java
                ).run {
                    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, this, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or Intent.FILL_IN_COMPONENT)
                }
                setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.todos_list, pendingIntentx)
            }

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, views)
    }

    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val viewIndex: Int = intent!!.getIntExtra("todo_id", 0)
        Log.d("debugging", "an item is clicked $viewIndex")
        //the default value gets used, which means that the receiver isn't receiving the intent data
        
        super.onReceive(context, intent)
    }
}
```

The problem is that the receiver isn't receiving the data which was put in the fillInIntent, the default  value 0 is getting printed by the last statement. I also tried setting the FILL_IN_COMPONENT flag as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718731/appwidget-setfillinintent-cant-handle-data-set-in-setdata-or-componentname), but that didn't work. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or Intent.FILL_IN_COMPONENT` with `PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE`. I think it is the `IMMUTABLE` that makes the intent can't be changed. As a result, you can't get the extra.